# how to integrate powershell with ASP.net web page

Tags: asp.net, soap, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

how to integrate powershell with ASP.net web page so any time any one click on asp.net page button . The powershell on the remote exchange server will execute and return the result . Also that result has to be send back to asp.net page to display on web page to user. can you please help on this.

Thanks
Swapnil Gangrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at code project article about [running powershell from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C). The sample code is following:

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    // create Powershell runspace

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    // open it

    runspace.Open();

    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

    // add an extra command to transform the script
    // output objects into nicely formatted strings

    // remove this line to get the actual objects
    // that the script returns. For example, the script

    // "Get-Process" returns a collection
    // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    // execute the script

    Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();

    // close the runspace

    runspace.Close();

    // convert the script result into a single string

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

But be careful with impersonating, because you can run this powershell as wrong user.

Comment: Provide a summary of the link, if it dies, your answer will become useless. [Please see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau here you are